# Getting Foundation 6 to work on IE8

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Is there any workaround that can make Foundation 6 work on IE8? I have a client who needs IE8 support so that the site at least doesn't break the layout.

I tried different methods described in different website but yet I couldn't figure out the solution. I tried the technique from [this site](https://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8) but it's not working for F6.

Comment: You would need to downgrade to an older version of Foundation, 6 does not support IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use Foundation 5, as 6 won't support it (see more at http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/compatibility.html). You can install Foundation 5 here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/

If you have any issues after that, the link you posted should answer any other questions you have.